# No variable member function declared in class?

Tags: c++

### can sombody explain to me why my code will not work, and how to fix it thanks :)

I keep recieving this error :

```
no 'int burrito::setName()' member function declared in class 'burrito'
```

My goal is to call a function from a different class file

My main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "burrito.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

burrito a;
a.setName("Ammar T.");


return 0;
}
```

My class header (burrito.h)

```
#ifndef BURRITO_H
#define BURRITO_H


class burrito
{
public:
    burrito();
};

#endif // BURRITO_H
```

My class file (burrito.cpp):

```
#include "burrito.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

burrito::setName()
{
  public:
    void setName(string x){
        name = x;


    };
burrito::getName(){

    string getName(){
        return name;
    };

}

burrito::variables(string name){
    string name;
               };

private:
    string name;
};
```

Comment: Needs jalapeno sauce.

Comment: You need to define all the functions in the header and in the cpp. Google a sample header program

Comment: Your burrito has no variables (data members) declared in the class.  Your `variables` method has *local* variables that disappear after execution leaves the method.

Comment: Your source file has `private` section and `};` not associated with anything.  Maybe you wanted to move these lines to the end of your Burrito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a mess. You need to write function prototypes in the header file and function definitions in the cpp file. You are missing some basic coding structures. See below and learn this pattern of coding:

This code should work and enjoy burritos !

**main():**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    burrito a;
    a.setName("Ammar T.");

    std::cout << a.getName() << "\n";

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**CPP file:**

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <string>

void burrito::setName(std::string x) { this->name = x; }
std::string burrito::getName() { return this->name; }
```

**Header file:**

```
#include <string>

class burrito
{
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    void setName(std::string);
    std::string getName();
    //variables(string name) {string name;} // What do you mean by this??
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Sorry for this mess, I'm new to c++

Comment: A common coding guideline is to provide parameter names in the declarations of methods.

Comment: @AmmarT glad it helped. Please mark it as an answer if you see it working :)

Comment: Do NOT put `using namespace std;` in the header file, this creates namespace pollution - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice

Comment: But this is for beginners? @archbishopofbanterbury

Comment: @FirstStep That does not mean that we should teach them poor coding conventions - it's best to learn good coding conventions right from the start

Comment: You are making a point.  I learned it that way and I am fairly doing good now. Thanks for the point I edited it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your poor little burrito is confused.  Confused burritos can't help much.

You may want your burrito declaration as:

```
class Burrito
{
public:
    Burrito();
    void set_name(const std::string& new_name);
    std::string get_name() const;
private:
    std::string name;
};
```

The methods could be defined in the source file as:

```
void
Burrito::set_name(const std::string& new_name)
{
  name = new_name;
}

std::string
Burrito::get_name() const
{
  return name;
}
```

Comment: this is too much for a beginner.

Comment: `set_name` needs a `void` return type in header file :)

Comment: Since I'm new to c++ I have no idea what alot of the things u did mean so I'll have to look it up, Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: Thanks for identifying a defect. :-).  Corrected.

Comment: @FirstStep:  How is this too much for a beginner?  I took the OP's code and organized it correctly.

Comment: What if he doesn't know what is to pass by reference? or why we use const with the parameter or inline?

Comment: @FirstStep I have no idea what either of those are, thats why I went with yours since it didn't add anything I didn't know.

Comment: @FirstStep: Then he has a poor education.  I recommend that references be taught before function creation.

Comment: @thomasmatthews Maybe you are right and I should go with your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The header file only has a constructor for the class. The member functions

```
   setName(string) and getName()
```

are not declared in the header file and that is why you get the error.
Also, you need to specify the return type for functions.

One way to do this would be

```
 //Header 
 //burrito.h   
class burrito{
   private:
   string burrito_name; 
   public:
       burrito();
       string getName(); 
       void setName(string);
             }

//burrito.cpp
#include "burrito.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string burrito::getName()
{
return burrito_name; 
}

void burrito::setName(string bname)
{
 bname =burrito_name;
}
```

Comment: the member function setName() needs a string as a parameter :)

Comment: @FirstStep Were you pointing to the setName() on the first line? I just edited it

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example for class in C++,
Save this in `burrito.cpp` file then compile and run it:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std;
class burrito {
public:
    void setName(string s);
    string getName();
private:
    string name;
};

void burrito::setName(string s) {
    name = s;
}
string burrito::getName() {
    return name;
}

int main() {
    burrito a;
    a.setName("Ammar T.");
    std::cout << a.getName() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```